# Can argparse forward arguments to other python files?

Tags: python, argparse

I'm writing a CLI with hundreds of arguments and sub modules in Python with argparse. For obvious reasons, I do not want these arguments all stacked in the same python file. Instead, I would prefer to delegate to other submodules and let users add their own submodule at will that will be automatically detected by the top level `argparser`.

As an example, we might have a directory that looks like the following:

```
- main.py
- foo.py
- bar.py
- baz/foo.py
...
```

One valid invocation of this CLI would be:

```
./main.py foo --help
```

This would bring up the help pane for the `argparse` module in `foo.py`

Another example would be:

```
./main.py baz foo --help
```

which would bring up the help pane for the `argparse` module in `baz/foo.py`.

And finally:

```
./main.py --help
```

Would print something like:

```
Options are:
  foo
  bar
  baz
```

If you haven't already guessed, this pattern is seen in `kubectl`, which seems to organize a plethora of options quite well.

Does a library like this exist or do I need to roll my own?

Comment: Yes. See [ansible](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/tree/stable-2.9/lib/ansible/cli) for some examples to get you started, where each subcommand is a module. It won't perfectly fit your example here (the nested package/modules requirement is out of the ordinary) but should give you some places to get started.

Comment: It looks like they rolled their own. I was hoping for a library that handled this problem generically. I know it's not much code, but anything helps.

Comment: It could be done with `argparse` functions in `main` and each script, but you'd have to do most of the work of calling the relevant scripts, and setting `sys.argv` appropriately.  That's too big of a topic to discuss here.

Comment: Keep in mind the `argparse` is primarily a parsing tool, a way of determining what your user wants. It is not an execution or delegating tool.  It parses `sys.argv` and returns a `args` namespace.  That's all (plus some error checking and help formatting).